# Errors: [Could not extract [elasticsearch.version] from [plugin-descriptor.properties] of the given plugin file.] on Elastic cloud

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elastic-cloud

When I install custom plugin to elastic cloud (https://cloud.elastic.co/deployment-features/extensions).

I got this error . I am uploading a zip which contains  plugin-descriptor.properties which has `elasticsearch.version=7.17.6`

```
Errors: [Could not extract [elasticsearch.version] from [plugin-descriptor.properties] of the given plugin file.]
```

Any help on how to solve the above issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that your file is valid, perhaps you forgot an <% somewhere which affect the file.

Here's my detailed article describing the solution : https://medium.com/@benbiga.badre/install-custom-plugin-in-elasticsearch-845925a22f3f

don't forget to hit the clap